# How to maximize JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-7

How to maximize `JFrame` while loading the form? I am using Netbeans 7.3.1 so I am unable to edit `initComponents()` auto generated code please suggest me any alternate way so that I can maximize my `JFrame` at start-up.

Comment: Change the properties file in design view.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Even in SO there are so many answers to that... Flagging....

Answer (score 2):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Rectangle bounds = getmaximizedBounds(); // set your maximized bounds
frame.setMaximizedBounds(bounds);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
JFrame.setState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
```

read about frame states [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setState%28int%29)